# What's the best way to inject a yaml file into an Argo workflow step?

Tags: go, kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

#### Summary:

We have a golang application that submits Argo workflows to a kubernetes cluster upon requests. I'd like to pass a yaml file to one of the steps and I'm wondering what are the options for doing this.

#### Environment:

- Argo: v2.4.2
- K8s: 1.13.12-gke.25

#### Additional details:

Eventually, I would like to pass this file to the test step as shown in this example:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-
spec:
  entrypoint: test
  templates:
  - name: test
    container:
      image: gcr.io/testproj/test:latest
      command: [bash]
      source: |
        python test.py --config_file_path=/path/to/config.yaml
```

The image used in this step would have a python script that receives the path to this file then accesses it.

To submit the Argo workflows with golang, we use the following dependencies:

- https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/pkg/client
- https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/pkg/apis

Thank you.

Comment: In which step you want to pass the `yaml`, can you share the workflow template?

Comment: @Crou thank you for the comment. I'm unable to share the code due to my employer's policy, but I'll post a basic example that could be representative enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1: pass the file as a parameter

[Workflow parameters](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/examples#parameters) are usually small bits of text or numbers. But if your yaml file is reasonably small, you could string-encode it and pass it as a parameter.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-
spec:
  entrypoint: test
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: yaml
      value: "string-encoded yaml"
  templates:
  - name: test
    container:
      image: gcr.io/testproj/test:latest
      command: [bash]
      source: |
        # In this case, the string-encoding should be BASH-compatible.
        python test.py --config_file_as_string="{{inputs.parameters.message}}"
```

## Option 2: pass the file as an artifact

Argo supports multiple types of [artifacts](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/tree/master/examples#artifacts). Perhaps the simplest for your use case is the [raw parameter](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/input-artifact-raw.yaml) type.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: test-
spec:
  entrypoint: test
  templates:
  - name: test
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: yaml
        path: /path/to/config.yaml
        raw:
          data: |
            this is
            the raw file
            contents
    container:
      image: gcr.io/testproj/test:latest
      command: [bash]
      source: |
        python test.py --config_file_path=/path/to/config.yaml
```

Besides `raw`, Argo supports "S3, Artifactory, HTTP, [and] Git" artifacts (among others, I think).

If, for example, you chose to use S3, you could upload the file from your golang app and then pass the S3 bucket and key as parameters.

## Golang client

I'm not familiar with the golang client, but passing parameters is certainly supported, and I *think* passing in a raw parameter should be supported as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I'll go with the parameter option. The file contents we'd like to pass are relatively small in size.